# jQuery FullCalendar multiple calendars, get dropped on calendar id

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar

I am using the jQuery `FullCalendar` by Adam Shaw. I am creating multiple calendars on the same page, and dragging external elements onto the calendars. I need to get the calendar id that the element was dropped onto in order to update in my database. What would be the easiest way to get the id?

I have tried using closest

```
$(this).closest('div.calendar').attr('id');
or
$(this).closest('div.fc').attr('id');
or
$(this).closest('div.fc-ltc').attr('id');
```

all of these result in `undefined`.

javascript (simplified)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#external-events div.external-event').each(function() {
            var eventObject = {
                    title: $.trim($(this).text())
            };
            $(this).draggable({
                    zIndex: 999,
                    revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                    revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });
    });

    $('.calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                    left: '',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: ''
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,
            drop: function(date, allDay,jsEvent, ui,) {

                    //GET calendar id                      
                    var calendarid = $(this).closest('div.calendar').attr('id');

                    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
                    copiedEventObject.start = date;
                    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                    // Using calendarid here
                    copiedEventObject.calendar = calendarid;

                    // Using calendarid here
                    $('#'+calendarid).fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                    $(this).hide();
            }

    });

});
```

html (simplified)

```
<div id='external-events'>
    <h4>Draggable Events</h4>
    <div class='external-event'>My Event 1</div>
    <div class='external-event'>My Event 2</div>
    <div class='external-event'>My Event 3</div>
    <div class='external-event'>My Event 4</div>
    <div class='external-event'>My Event 5</div>
</div>

<div id='calendar1' class='calendar'></div>
<div id='calendar2' class='calendar'></div>
<div id='calendar3' class='calendar'></div>
```

So how would I find the div id of the calendar (ie. `calendar1`) that the event was dropped on?

---

**Update**

I found that by using [`.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint) and `jsEvent`s `screenX`/`screenY` coordinates where the event was dropped I could then find the parent calendar id.

```
var calendarid = $(document.elementFromPoint(jsEvent.screenX, jsEvent.screenY)).closest('div.calendar').attr('id');
```

updated js

```
    $('.calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                    left: '',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: ''
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,
            drop: function(date, allDay,jsEvent, ui,) {

                    //GET calendar id                      
                    var calendarid = $(document.elementFromPoint(jsEvent.screenX, jsEvent.screenY)).closest('div.calendar').attr('id');

                    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
                    copiedEventObject.start = date;
                    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                    // Using calendarid here
                    copiedEventObject.calendar = calendarid;

                    // Using calendarid here
                    $('#'+calendarid).fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                    $(this).hide();
            }

    });
```

Is [`.elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint) / `document.elementFromPoint(jsEvent.screenX, jsEvent.screenY)` an accurate and/or best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I do have the solution and its working fine for past one year for me, it might help you as well.

```
initialize the calendar
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
function initializeCalendar( calId /*pass as many custom parameters*/ ) {
    $('#calendar'+calId ).fullCalendar({
          drop: function(date, allDay,jsEvent, ui,) {
                //GET calendar id                      
                var calendarid = calId;

                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                // Using calendarid here
                copiedEventObject.calendar = calendarid;

                // Using calendarid here
                $('#'+calendarid).fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                $(this).hide();
          }     
    });
 }
```

This is so far the most accurate and optimized way i have came across.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like we can use view parameter to identify the id. This worked for me. Create one function to pull out the id. And call it from the callbacks functions with view as parameter.

```
function getCalendarId(view) {
        return (view.calendar.view.el.parents('div.calendar').attr('id'))
    }


function onSelectTimeFrame(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
                let calendarId = getCalendarname(view);
                //Use calendarId.
    }
```